# Eclipse / Sonar Analysis - java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

Tags: eclipse, out-of-memory, sonarqube, permgen

Good morning,
i am trying to syncronize my Eclipse project with the Sonar server we have in our Company. I tried with 2 completely different computers/environments but cannot find a solution, even if I  tried to apply every suggested tip found here (stackOverflow) or elsewhere.

It seems (as clearly explained by the stacktrace) that I may have a memory lack and, since the project is really huge, it may be obvious, but pheraps I cannot (or I don't know) how to launch eclipse with more memory.
I modified the eclipse.ini as below:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140603-1326
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
1024m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms512m
-Xmx2048m
-XX:MaxPermSize=2048m
```

but nothing.

Later modified the Windows / Preferences / SonarQube / JVM arguments for analysis with:

```
-Xmx2048m
```

Tried later Windows / Preferences / SonarQube / Preview Analysis Properties with:

```
wrapper.java.maxmemory  = 6000
```

but nothing. Eclipse cannot finish analysis (maybe just cannot store data in local db).

These are the environment specs (of the best machine...):

Windows 8 64bit - 8GB RAM

java version "1.7.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0-b147)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 21.0-b17, mixed mode)

Eclipse Standard/SDK
Version: Luna Release (4.4.0)
Build id: 20140612-0600

```
Retrieve remote issues of project PREPRODUZIONE...
Start SonarQube analysis on PREPRODUZIONE...
INFO: SonarQube Server 4.3
11:09:32.970 INFO  - Incremental mode
11:09:32.972 INFO  - Load batch settings
11:09:33.196 INFO  - User cache: C:\Users\alex\.sonar\cache
11:09:33.201 INFO  - Install plugins
11:09:33.235 INFO  - Include plugins: 
11:09:33.235 INFO  - Exclude plugins: devcockpit, jira, pdfreport, views, report, buildstability, scmactivity, buildbreaker
11:09:41.588 INFO  - Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:h2:C:\ECLIPSE\3.3.2\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\PREPRODUZIONE\org.sonar.ide.eclipse.core\.sonartmp\preview1406279373883-0
11:09:42.716 INFO  - Initializing Hibernate
11:09:45.471 INFO  - Load project settings
11:09:45.553 INFO  - Apply project exclusions
11:09:45.653 INFO  - -------------  Scan PREPRODUZIONE
11:09:45.657 INFO  - Load module settings
11:09:46.788 INFO  - Loading technical debt model...
11:09:46.794 INFO  - Loading technical debt model done: 6 ms
11:09:46.794 INFO  - Loading rules...
11:09:47.056 INFO  - Loading rules done: 262 ms
11:09:47.065 INFO  - Configure Maven plugins
11:09:47.127 INFO  - Compare to previous analysis (2014-07-10)
11:09:47.133 INFO  - Compare over 30 days (2014-06-25, analysis of 2014-07-10 00:13:19.304)
11:09:47.140 INFO  - Compare to previous version (2014-07-10)
11:09:47.425 INFO  - Loaded quality gate 'RGI Standard - java '
11:09:47.824 INFO  - Base dir: C:\ECLIPSE\3.3.2\PREPRODUZIONE
11:09:47.824 INFO  - Working dir: C:\ECLIPSE\3.3.2\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\PREPRODUZIONE\org.sonar.ide.eclipse.core
11:09:47.824 INFO  - Source dirs: C:\ECLIPSE\3.3.2\PREPRODUZIONE\src\java
11:09:47.824 INFO  - Binary dirs: C:\ECLIPSE\3.3.2\PREPRODUZIONE\bin
11:09:47.824 INFO  - Source encoding: windows-1252, default locale: it_IT
11:09:47.825 INFO  - Index files
11:09:48.879 INFO  - 1095 files indexed
11:09:53.579 INFO  - Quality profile for java: RGI Standard
11:09:53.579 INFO  - Quality profile for xml: Sonar way
11:09:53.898 INFO  - JaCoCo report not found.
11:09:53.899 INFO  - JaCoCo IT report not found.
11:09:53.899 INFO  - JaCoCo reports not found.
11:09:53.915 INFO  - Sensor JavaSquidSensor...
11:09:54.088 INFO  - Java Main Files AST scan...
11:09:54.091 INFO  - 1091 source files to be analyzed
11:10:04.092 INFO  - 226/1091 files analyzed, current is C:\ECLIPSE\3.3.2\PREPRODUZIONE\src\java\it\boh\dbo\Vehicle.java
11:10:13.450 INFO  - 1091/1091 source files analyzed
11:10:13.587 INFO  - Java Main Files AST scan done: 19499 ms
11:10:13.624 INFO  - Java bytecode scan...
11:10:14.759 INFO  - Java bytecode scan done: 1135 ms
11:10:14.759 INFO  - Java Test Files AST scan...
11:10:14.759 INFO  - 0 source files to be analyzed
11:10:14.759 INFO  - Java Test Files AST scan done: 0 ms
11:10:14.760 INFO  - 0/0 source files analyzed
11:10:16.066 INFO  - Sensor JavaSquidSensor done: 22151 ms
11:10:16.066 INFO  - Sensor QProfileSensor...
11:10:16.067 INFO  - Sensor QProfileSensor done: 1 ms
11:10:16.067 INFO  - Sensor FindbugsSensor...
11:10:16.068 INFO  - Execute Findbugs 2.0.3...
11:10:17.667 INFO  - Found findbugs plugin: /C:/Users/alex/.sonar/cache/108e4763f8b1f4a0e9de5d1fa2aba85b/sonar-fb-contrib-plugin-1.2.jar_unzip/META-INF/lib/fb-contrib-4.8.5.jar
11:10:17.827 INFO  - Findbugs output report: C:\ECLIPSE\3.3.2\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\PREPRODUZIONE\org.sonar.ide.eclipse.core\findbugs-result.xml
Frame type field is null:false
11:11:20.205 INFO  - Execute Findbugs 2.0.3 done: 64137 ms
11:11:20.287 INFO  - Sensor FindbugsSensor done: 64220 ms
11:11:20.287 INFO  - Sensor CpdSensor...
11:11:20.288 INFO  - SonarEngine is used for java
11:11:20.294 INFO  - Cross-project analysis disabled
11:11:23.923 INFO  - Sensor CpdSensor done: 3636 ms
11:11:23.923 INFO  - Sensor PmdSensor...
11:11:23.924 INFO  - Execute PMD 5.1.1...
11:11:24.017 INFO  - Java version: 1.5
11:11:24.095 INFO  - PMD configuration: C:\ECLIPSE\3.3.2\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\PREPRODUZIONE\org.sonar.ide.eclipse.core\pmd.xml
11:11:38.763 INFO  - Execute PMD 5.1.1 done: 14839 ms
11:11:38.871 INFO  - Sensor PmdSensor done: 14948 ms
11:11:38.871 INFO  - Sensor XmlSensor...
11:11:39.069 INFO  - Sensor XmlSensor done: 198 ms
11:11:39.070 INFO  - Sensor LineCountSensor...
11:11:39.085 INFO  - Sensor LineCountSensor done: 15 ms
11:11:39.086 INFO  - Sensor SurefireSensor...
11:11:39.087 INFO  - parsing C:\ECLIPSE\3.3.2\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\PREPRODUZIONE\org.sonar.ide.eclipse.core\build\surefire-reports
11:11:39.087 WARN  - Reports path not found: C:\ECLIPSE\3.3.2\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\PREPRODUZIONE\org.sonar.ide.eclipse.core\build\surefire-reports
11:11:39.087 INFO  - Sensor SurefireSensor done: 1 ms
11:11:39.087 INFO  - Sensor CheckstyleSensor...
11:11:39.088 INFO  - Execute Checkstyle 5.6...
11:11:39.161 INFO  - Checkstyle configuration: C:\ECLIPSE\3.3.2\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\PREPRODUZIONE\org.sonar.ide.eclipse.core\checkstyle.xml
11:11:54.484 INFO  - Execute Checkstyle 5.6 done: 15396 ms
11:11:54.484 INFO  - Sensor CheckstyleSensor done: 15397 ms
11:11:54.484 INFO  - Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor...
11:11:54.733 INFO  - Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor done: 249 ms
11:11:54.734 INFO  - Sensor ProfileEventsSensor...
11:11:54.745 INFO  - Sensor ProfileEventsSensor done: 11 ms
11:11:54.745 INFO  - Sensor ProjectLinksSensor...
11:11:54.751 INFO  - Sensor ProjectLinksSensor done: 6 ms
11:11:55.040 INFO  - Execute decorators...
11:13:35.682 INFO  - Export results to C:\ECLIPSE\3.3.2\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\PREPRODUZIONE\org.sonar.ide.eclipse.core\sonar-report.json
11:13:36.629 INFO  - Store results in database
Exception in thread "main" org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncherMain.execute(BatchLauncherMain.java:41)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncherMain.main(BatchLauncherMain.java:59)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.IsolatedClassloader.loadClass(IsolatedClassloader.java:94)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.SqlASTFactory.class$(SqlASTFactory.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.SqlASTFactory.getASTNodeType(SqlASTFactory.java:103)
    at antlr.ASTFactory.create(ASTFactory.java:152)
    at antlr.ASTFactory.create(ASTFactory.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.updateStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:327)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:239)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:254)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:185)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1651)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:93)
    at org.sonar.jpa.session.JpaDatabaseSession.createQuery(JpaDatabaseSession.java:184)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.UpdateStatusJob.setFlags(UpdateStatusJob.java:133)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.UpdateStatusJob.disablePreviousSnapshot(UpdateStatusJob.java:95)
```

Any other suggestions?

Thanks
Alessandro

Answer (score 2):

Try going to Window / Preferences / SonarQube and enter your maxPermSize value in the "JVM arguments for preview analysis" box:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Set the below environment variable and the try to run the sonar runner
Variable Name: SONAR_RUNNER_OPTS
Variable Value: -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m

Comment: Hello,thanks for the answer. You mean the windows env. variables? I tried, restarted eclipse, relaunched sonar runner, but still have the same problem

Comment: No, In the configuration file you should change these parameters.